# Can't pass through "" to powershell using ProcessStartInfo arguments, C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, powershell, processstartinfo

I'm unable to pass through an argument to powershell which contains `""`. When I use the equivalent code but change the application to cmd the `""` are able to pass through.

The argument I'd like powershell to execute is:

```
Copy-Item -Path "{Working Directory}\W11F-assets\" -Destination "C:\\Windows\W11F-assets" -Recurse
```

This is the code that's calling that function:

```
    ProcessStartInfo movefile = new ProcessStartInfo("powershell.exe");
    string flocation = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    movefile.UseShellExecute = true;
    movefile.Arguments = "Copy-Item -Path \"" + flocation + "\\W11F-assets\" -Destination \"C:\\Windows\\W11F-assets\" -Recurse";
    Process.Start(movefile);
```

Comment: You have a lot of escaping issues. You can tell this by looking at the syntax highlighting. If this is literally part of the command: `"C:\\Windows\W11F-assets"` then I am guessing you meant to escape both slashes, not just the first one. And in your actual C# code, you need to escape every single slash, so those \\ are going to look like \\\\ in the C# source. Also note the first \" in the command, did you mean to escape that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to solve issue by replacing `\"` with `'`.

Comment: That's a viable workaround, but it's important to note that it would require extra work for paths that themselves happen to contain `'` characters. A proper solution with `"` quoting is possible, which works will all paths as-is, given that paths cannot contain `"` characters (on Windows).

Answer (score 1):

When commands are passed to the PowerShell CLI's (positionally implied) `-Command` (`-c`) parameter, any *unescaped* `"` chars. are *stripped* during command-line processing, and only *then* are the arguments (space-joined to form a single string, if there are multiple ones) interpreted as PowerShell code.

Therefore:

- `"` characters that are to be retained as part of the command(s) must be `\"`-escaped.
- Additionally, to prevent potentially unwanted whitespace normalization (folding multiple adjacent spaces into one), it is best to enclose the command(s) in unescaped embedded `"..."` overall.

To fully spell out a solution that should work, with explicit use of `-Command` and also `-NoProfile` to avoid usually unnecessary loading of the profile files, and with extra spaces for conceptual clarity, taking advantage of interpolated (`$`) verbatim (`@`) strings (inside of which `\` can be used as-is and `"` must be escaped as `""`):

```
movefile.Arguments = 
  $@"-NoProfile -Command "" Copy-Item -Path \""{flocation}\W11F-assets\"" -Destination \""C:\Windows\W11F-assets\"" -Recurse "" ";
```