# having trouble with Double Quotes between C# and PowerShell

Tags: c#, powershell

This is my code [working in powershell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kXFS.png), but to put it in C# I must replace "$string" to "$string2"; but it's not working (: it must be "$string" to work...
I tried '$string' and ($string) and a lot but just this "$string" working.
Help ?

```
Powershell Code Working 100% :
$string2 = C:/Users/Sycho/Desktop/youtube-dl.exe -F https://youtu.be/f1A7SdVTlok | Out-String -stream | Select-String 133 ; "$string2".SubString(105)
```

```
     var mainForm = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form1>().Single();
     string urlBoxText3 = mainForm.Controls["URL_BOX"].Text;
     ProcessStartInfo startInfo6 = new ProcessStartInfo();
     startInfo6.FileName = @"powershell.exe";
     startInfo6.Arguments = "$string2 = C:/Users/Sycho/Desktop/youtube-dl.exe -F " + urlBoxText3 + "| Out-String -stream | Select-String 133 ; \"$string2\".SubString(105)";
     startInfo6.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
     startInfo6.RedirectStandardError = true;
     startInfo6.UseShellExecute = false;
     startInfo6.CreateNoWindow = true;
     startInfo6.Verb = "runas";
     Process process6 = new Process();
     process6.StartInfo = startInfo6;
     process6.Start();
     string output = process6.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
     label4.Text = output;
```

Comment: Show us your C# code.

Comment: Please include your PowerShell code as text, not as an image

Comment: @RobertHarvey a program to download youtube videos using youtube-dl....i shared all you need to know to help me.

Comment: Why are you using PowerShell just to run an exe file from C#, rather than just running it directly with the new process?

Comment: @stuartd I just want to get the video size...so I can't do it with the exe I am doing it with powershell and filtering output

Comment: What I mean is, you can replicate the successful powershell call by setting the process file name to `C:/Users/Sycho/Desktop/youtube-dl.exe` and the arguments to `"-F " + urlBoxText3`. Then you can use C#'s string methods to extract the part you want from the output.

Comment: @stuartd see this plz https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUmXV.png  .......... can I show MB only ?with C#'s string methods ?

Comment: Why are you executing `powershell.exe` anyway? You can execute a Powershell script directly using [`System.Management.Automation.Powershell`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/hosting/adding-and-invoking-commands?view=powershell-7.2)

Comment: _can I show MB only_ - sure. But it's not possible to tell you _how_ from just an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You say that PowerShell must ultimately see `"$string2".SubString(105)` for your command to work.
- When you call PowerShell via its [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), `powershell.exe`, and pass commands to it via the (positionally implied) `-Command` / `-c` parameter, you must *escape* `"` characters as `\"` in order for PowerShell to retain them as part of the command(s) to execute *after command-line parsing*.

  - This is explained in more detail in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71166188/45375).

Therefore, replace `\"$string2\"` with `\\\"$string2\\\"` (sic).

---

Taking a step back: You could streamline your code as follows, which obviates the need for enclosing `$string2` in `"..."`

```
startInfo6.Arguments = "$string2 = (C:/Users/Sycho/Desktop/youtube-dl.exe -F " + urlBoxText3 + " | Select-String 133).Line; $string2.SubString(105)";
```

- By accessing the `.Line` property on the output object emitted by the `Select-String` call, a *string* - the matching line - is directly returned (rather than the match-info object that is emitted by default).
- `Out-String -Stream` was removed, because it is unnecessary: PowerShell exhibits this behavior *by default* when calling *external programs* such as `youtube-dl.exe`.